# Multiple categories for a game in itunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We just published our game to iTunes and assigned it to the "Games > Card" category.  We noticed, however, that some apps like Uno live under the Top Charts for both Card games and Board games.

Is there a way to assign a game to live under multiple sub-categories?  I noticed that for podcasts, there is XML where you can set multiple categories.  (Though only one is the 'primary')  Is there something similar within XCode for assigning categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You can choose 2 categories and up to 2 sub-categories in the Games-category on iTunes Connect.

**Screenshot from iTunes Connect:**

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, app categories are set in iTunes Connect only...